# IE7, IE8 Issue with jQuery .clone()

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, clone

On my page I have developed a horizontal scrolling carousel. On page load I am cloning each of the `<li>`'s and using `appendTo()` to add them onto the end of the list.

The issue I am having in IE7 and IE8 is as follows: Each of the `<a>`'s within the `<li>` has a css `:hover`/`:focus` which displays an inner `<div>`. In the aforementioned browsers when I hover over the cloned element, it shows the hover state, but on the element it has been cloned **from** rather than the new element!

Any idea what could be causing this?

My markup is as follows:

```
<ul class="people-carousel">
    <li>
        <a style="background-image: url(/images/placeholder/pc-1.jpg)" href="#">
            <div class="hover">
                <span class="pc-name">Name here</span>
                <span class="pc-position">Position</span>
                <span class="pc-view">View profile</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="background-image: url(/images/placeholder/pc-1.jpg)" href="#">
            <div class="hover">
                <span class="pc-name">Name here</span>
                <span class="pc-position">Position</span>
                <span class="pc-view">View profile</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a style="background-image: url(/images/placeholder/pc-1.jpg)" href="#">
            <div class="hover">
                <span class="pc-name">Name here</span>
                <span class="pc-position">Position</span>
                <span class="pc-view">View profile</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </li>
</ul><!-- /.people-carousel -->
```

And my jQuery is basically the following:

```
var list = _this.find('.people-carousel');
list.find('li').clone().appendTo(list);
```

The CSS is just a basic `:hover`, but is as follows:

```
/* Default */
.people-carousel .hover {
    position: absolute;
    top:40px;right:0;left:0;
    height: 107px;
    background: #ff6634;
    padding: 18px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;

    -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 50% 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 100%;

    -webkit-transform: scale(.5);
    -moz-transform: scale(.5);
    -ms-transform: scale(.5);
    -o-transform: scale(.5);
    transform: scale(.5);

    -webkit-transition: .1s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: .1s ease-out;
    -ms-transition: .1s ease-out;
    -o-transition: .1s ease-out;
    transition: .1s ease-out;
}

/* Hover */
.people-carousel a:hover .hover, .people-carousel a:focus .hover {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;

    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like another wonderful IE bug with CSS psuedo-selectors. I would suggest hooking up the `:hover` and `:focus` events via jQuery instead of CSS. It's backwards semantically, but if you need to support IE7/8 you sometimes have to do stupid things to make it work.

```
/* Hover */
.people-carousel a.highlight .hover {
    opacity: 1;
    top: 0;

    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1);
    -o-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
}
```

```js
$('.people-carousel')
    .on('focus mouseenter', 'a', function() {
        $(this).addClass('highlight');
    })
    .on('blur mouseleave', 'a', function() {
        $(this).removeClass('highlight');
    });
```

Note I used delegated event hanlders so that the events will work for any `li` elements you append dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That approach did indeed work, but I did a bit more digging into the issue. Turns out it was to do with Selectivizr, so it was copying the original events over to the new elements for IE!